# Moving website to new host, which .htaccess to use?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

I have not done this before and am confused on a couple issues.

Currently the live site is on Bluehost, created with Frontpage (yes I know), the new site is under development with Wordpress and is on Cloudways.

The registered domain will be kept but what I don't understand is how to 
handle redirects from the old page structure to the new one.

So as I understand it when it is time to go live with the new site on Cloudways the domain will be pointed to their server and somehow all the temp URL's on Cloudways get updated with the domain name...

**So my question is:**

The URLs on the current live site and dev site do not match, for example:

Current live site:

```
http://www.example.com/Whoweare.htm
```

and on the dev/new site they are:

```
http://www.example.com/who-we-are/
```

How do I redirect these?

I have looked at 301 redirects but which `.htaccess` file do they go in, the one on the old site or on the new site?

How can I test my redirects before going live with the new site?

Comment: "the one on the old site or on the new site?" - Since you only have one domain, the old and new site will effectively become the same singular website at the time the domain is switched - so there is only one place the `.htaccess` could possibly go.

Comment: I could ftp into the Bluehost site where I would find a .htaccess file or I could ftp into the Cloudways site where I would find another .htaccess file. But I think I understand now that after the domain is pointed to Cloudways the redirects need to go there...

Answer (score 1):

There is only one `.htaccess` file that should be on your site and that should be the site root. In the file add a single redirect line for each of the pages that need to be redirected using the htaccess command...

`Redirect 301 /oldfile.htm /newfile.htm`

So in other words using your example you would add a line to the .htaccess file reading...

`Redirect 301 /Whoweare.htm /who-we-are/`

Comment: which .htaccess file? The one on the old site or the new site?

Comment: On the old site.

Comment: ok, but the old sites hosting will be cancelled..not sure I understand how this works... it also seems there is no way to test this.

Comment: My apologies I got it back to front, was thinking of a previous question from someone else. In your instance it would go into the htaccess file on the new site. Since you are not changing domains you won't run into too many issues, you're not trying to forward a domain connection, you're basically changing the names of your pages and so you can do the same thing as in the answer but in the new site.

Comment: I see thanks. But then there is no way to test this until I point the domain away from the bluehost site to the dev site, ie. go live with the new site?

Comment: There is, I will make the assumption here that you have assigned the new site a temporary domain (such as dev.domain.com). As the redirects are relative you can test it by going to dev.domain.com/Whoweare.htm and that should take you to dev.domain.com/who-we-are/

Comment: So to make sure I understand: I would go to the .htaccess file on the new dev server and add the line:` Redirect 301 /whoweare.htm http://dev.domain.com/who-we-are/`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo of mine, the redirect doesn't need the dev domain so it would be...
`Redirect 301 /whoweare.htm /who-we-are`

Comment: Just a point... since the new site is WordPress, there will already be existing mod_rewrite directives (the WP front controller). It's not recommended to mix redirects from both mod_alias (`Redirect`) and mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) as you can get conflicts. In this case the WP front controller will _try_ to route the request _before_ the mod_alias `Redirect` occurs. Ideally this should be changed to a mod_rewrite redirect and placed _before_ the existing WP directives. eg. `RewriteRule ^Whoweare\.htm /who-we-are/ [R=301,L]`.

Comment: "But then there is no way to test this until I point the domain away..." - You test it by manually navigating to the old URLs on the new site (or setting up some kind of unit test - since it looks like you are going to have to spend some time mapping the old/new URLs anyway).

Comment: @w3dk I understand (mostly) the Redirect 301 version but I don't quite get the RewriteRule version.

Comment: It is an alternate form of redirecting. In the rewrite rule version what you are doing is opening up the existing .htaccess file that WordPress comes with. You identify the section with the existing rewrite rules and before those rules you can add `RewriteRule ^Whoweare\.htm /who-we-are/ [R=301,L]` What this does is effectively the same as the redirect 301 I gave you but it uses the rewrite engine to perform the change since the rewrite engine is already active through the WordPress .htaccess file. @w3dk points out...

Comment: that it isn't good to mix mod_alias and mod_rewrite due to potential conflicts. I have never personally encountered such a conflict but it would certainly work his way as well.

Comment: I tried both versions and they both work. I have put the RewriteRule at the very top of the .htaccess file before anything from Wordpress and before the RewriteEngine On directive but it still seems to work........

Comment: @user2250892 Yes, they will both work in this instance, but mixing the directives has potential to cause problems in the future. These two modules work independently and run at different times during the request - despite the apparent order of the directives in `.htaccess`. (In your code, even if `Redirect` is at the start of the file, mod_rewrite would internally rewrite the request to `index.php` first (providing the old files were removed). Only then will the `Redirect` directive be processed, overriding the earlier rewrite. So, if nothing else, it is extra work.)

Comment: @user2250892 `RewriteEngine` - this is only required _once_ in the file. It can occur multiple times, but the last instance wins and controls the entire file. Ideally, you would just have one `RewriteEngine On` directive at the top of the file - simply for readability. But when you have different "plugins" writing to the `.htaccess` file, it is not always practical. (A "feature" of this is that you can always place a `RewriteEngine Off` directive at the very end of the file to disable mod_rewrite, instead of having to comment out large sections or find all the `RewriteEngine` directives.)